# MYSQL select data from two tables with conditions

Tags: mysql, select

So I basically got a task which is to create a single query to retrieve the total order as Number_Of_Order and total sales of all orders as Total_Sales_Amount. My main problem would be in creating the conditions for Normal and Promotion.

Orders Table

| Order_ID | Sales_type |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Normal |
| 12 | Promo |
| 13 | Normal |
| 14 | Promo |
| 15 | Normal |
| 16 | Promo |

Orders_Products Table

| Order_Product_ID | Order_ID | Normal_Price | Promotion_Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 | 50 | 25 |
| 101 | 12 | 100 | 80 |
| 102 | 12 | 60 | 50 |
| 103 | 13 | 40 | 20 |
| 104 | 14 | 50 | 25 |
| 105 | 15 | 40 | 30 |
| 106 | 15 | 300 | 250 |
| 107 | 16 | 150 | 100 |
| 108 | 16 | 75 | 60 |

Expected result :

| Number_Of_Order | Total_Sales_Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Total number of Order_ID from Order table 6 | total sales from Orders_Products table according to Sales_type price |

Comment: Please add the expected result you want to build.

Comment: Please don't use image in your question.

Comment: Noted and I also have insert the expected result

Comment: Don't describe your intended result, but show it. It is correct your expected outcome contains one row only and the first column will have the value 6? You are provoking misleading answers by not showing the result.

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Comment: Done I've already edited the table without picture

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is `Total number of Order_ID from Order table 6` the **exact** result you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join along with a `CASE` expression to use the correct price.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.Order_ID) AS Number_Of_Order,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.Sales_Type = 'Normal'
                THEN op.Normal_Price ELSE op.Promotion_Price END) AS Total_Sales_Amount
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Orders_Products op
    ON op.Order_ID = o.Order_ID;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use LEFT JOIN? Also note OP requested "Total number of Order_ID from Order table" which is 6, but your query will return 9.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Should a certain order have no entry in the order products table, an inner join would remove it from the report.  I should also be wrapping my `SUM(...)` in `COALESCE` to assign zero in this case, but I'm feeling lazy.

Comment: `but your query will return 9` ... no it won't.  It will return _one_ record containing the count and sum over the entire table.

Comment: It will return 9 in your column "Number_Of_Order", but it seems to be intended to return 6 there. Changing COUNT(*) to COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_id) would solve this. Anyway, maybe just the description in the question is already wrong.

Comment: You were right about the distinct count.